# How can we add a attachment tab while creating an envelope via template using REST API?

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any REST API call to add a attachment tab while sending envelopes? For this I am referring to this [link](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Signer%20Attachment%20Tab.htm), but I don't know how to use this. Can you please tel me the full API call?

Answer (score 0):

It's just like any other DocuSign tab, you just need to reference the name properly and set its parameters. Here's an example that would send one signature tab and one signer attachment tab:

```
POST v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

{
  "emailSubject": "Please sign this document",
  "documents": [
    {
      "name": "test.pdf",
      "documentId": "1"
    }
  ],
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "documentId": "1",
              "yPosition": "100",
              "xPosition": "100",
              "tabLabel": "Signature Tab",
            }
          ],
          "signerAttachmentTabs": [
            {
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "documentId": "1",
              "yPosition": "100",
              "xPosition": "200",
              "required": "true",
              "tabLabel": "Signer Attachment Tab",
            }
          ]
        },
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "name": "Jon Dough",
        "email": "jon.dough@email.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": "sent"
}
```